# How to split user input integer into a list, where each entry is 2 digits?

Tags: python, integer

I'm trying to split an arbitrarily long user input integer into a list where each entry is 2 digits, and if the number has an odd amount of integers, put the only single digit as the first digit. (Where I will then proceed to put a zero in front of it)

I know that putting user integer input into a list looks like:

```
userintegerlist = [int(i) for i in str(user_input)]
print userintegerlist
```

And my input (say it's `45346`) will look like `[4,5,3,4,6]`.  But I want it to look like: `[4,53,46]`. Or if input is `68482238`, it will be: `[68,48,22,38]`.

Is this possible? All the code is in Python by the way.

Comment: if you know how to use a list comprehension, you must know how to use a regular `for` loop.  iterate over `range(len(user_input))[::2]` and take the elements `i` and `i + 1`.  i don't know that this was worth a post here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with string methods fairly easily, as other answers have already shown.  I direct you to the related [grouper recipe in itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

I want to mention that it may be more efficient to do it with maths:

```
>>> n = 45346
>>> output = []
>>> while n:
...     output.append(n % 100)
...     n //= 100
...     
>>> output = output[::-1]
>>> print output
[4, 53, 46]
```

Comment: Oneline version of this solution: [n % 100**(i+1) // 100**i for i in range(0, math.ceil(math.ceil(math.log10(n))/2))][::-1]

Answer (score 0):

```
s = raw_input()
if(len(s)%2 ==1):
    s = '0'+s
list = []
for i in range(len(s)/2):
    list.append(int(s[2*i:2*i+2]))
print list
```

After taking the input string, check if its of odd length, and if yes, prefix a 0 to it.
Then , iterate over the string , taking two characters at a time , cast that substring to int , and append it in a list.
It's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> split = lambda s: (len(s)&1 and [s[0]] or []) + [s[i-1]+s[i] for i in range(len(s)-1,0,-2)][::-1]
>>> split("45346")
['4', '53', '46']
>>> split("68482238")
['68', '48', '22', '38']
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an input such as `'12345'` what you can do is turn that into a list and then iterate over it in reverse trying to pop two elements at a time and then inserting those at the beginning of the list as integers (after joining them together).

If you fail to pop a second element, then you just prefix the popped element with a 0 and also insert that at the beginning of the output list.

Here's a very dirty solution that attempts this:

```
def foo(user_input):
    transformed_input = list(user_input)
    out = []
    while transformed_input:
        a = transformed_input.pop()
        try:
            b = transformed_input.pop()
            a = b + a
        except IndexError:
            a = '0' + a 
        out.insert(0, a)
    return out
```

For an input such as `'345'` you get `['03', '45']`

And then for `'3456'` you get `['34', '56']`

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

The strategy in my code is to create a mirror list and pair up the elements between the two lists

```
 user_input = '123192873918271'
    split_input = list(user_input)

#EXAMINE WHETHER THE LIST HAS AND ODD OR EVENT NUMBER OF ENTRIES
if len(user_input)%2==1 :

    #create a mirror list that we will pair the original one
    mirror_list = ['0']+ split_input 

    #pair up the elements in both lists
    final_list = [i+j for i,j in zip(mirror_list, split_input)]
elif len(user_input)%2==0:

    #in this case, we pair up the list with itself, with a 1 element shift
    final_list = [i+j for i,j in zip(split_input[:-1], split_input[1:])]

for i in final_list:
 print i

    01
    12
    23
    31
    19
    92
    28
    87
    73
    39
    91
    18
    82
    27
    71
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the items using the same iterator on the pair, without using any indexing on the string:

```
user_input = '45346'
user_input = '0'+user_input if len(user_input)%2 else user_input
gi = [iter(user_input)]*2
r = [''.join(z) for z in zip(*gi)]
print(r)
```

produces

```
['04', '53', '46']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import math
n = 2384920394837493
print([(n//(100**i))%100 for i in range(math.ceil(math.log(n, 100)), -1, -1)][bool(math.log(n,100)%1):]
```

**Outputs:**

```
[23, 84, 92, 3, 94, 83, 74, 93]
```