# How do I receive input in Python with possible whitespaces anywhere?

Tags: python, python-3.x

all I am very new to Python. I want to receive input integers with possible white spaces. Here is an example.

```
if I input 1234 I receive [1,2,3,4].
if I input 12 34 I receive [1,2,3,4].
if I input 012 4 I receive [0,1,2,4].
```

How can I do that? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: you should parse the line input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Split user input integer into list, where each entry is 2 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882040/python-split-user-input-integer-into-list-where-each-entry-is-2-digits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = '12 34'


data = data.replace(" ", "")
list = []

for d in data:
    list.append(int(d))
print list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input_string = '1234'
print(list(input_string.replace(' ', '')))

input_string ='12 34'
print(list(input_string.replace(' ', '')))

input_string ='012 4'
print(list(input_string.replace(' ', '')))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['0', '1', '2', '4']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test each character as a digit and simultaneously convert to a list of ints:

```
for s in ('1234','12 34', '1 2 3 4', '012 4'):
    print([int(n) for n in s if n.isdigit()])
```

Or, use a functional approach:

```
for s in ('1234','12 34', '1 2 3 4', '012 4'):
    print(map(int,filter(lambda c: c.isdigit(), s)))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can receive input like this yourInput = input("Insert your input:")

to check if you have a whitespace you can compare your string with a whitespace " "

```
inputIntegers = input("Input your Integers with whitespaces:")
output = []
for i in inputIntegers:
    if(i != " "):
        output.append(i)
```

output is then what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
re.findall(r'[0-9]','12 34')

['1', '2', '3', '4']

list(map(int, re.findall(r'[0-9]','012 4')))
# To get as integer elements

[0, 1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print map(int,''.join("12 3 4".split()))
```